# search on two WFEs

Tags: sharepoint-server, search

I have two WFEs for manual failover in case one WFE dies. The search is running on one WFE but it does not list the second server in it's topology page. Also, when this server is down, search stops. I am  not able to start the service on the second WFE. Do I need to create a new Search Application on the secnd WFE?

Comment: Which version of SP are you using (the configuration steps differ depending on the version)?

Comment: 2013 on premise on win 2012 r2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you trying to start service on second WFE, any error?
You should be able to do this:

1. Services - Central Administration > System Settings > [Manage services
   on servers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/start-or-stop-a-service)
2. After this, You need to [create new topology and apply it](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/change-the-default-search-topology). For simpliest way you can use [this application](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/scottstewart/2015/04/29/powershell-ui-to-modify-sharepoint-search-topology/).

*Hope it helps!*

Comment: this actually worked liked a charm. Thank you!  Important to note that all farm servers need to be on while running the powershell command:

Comment: After applying the above and turning off the first WFE server to test it again I receive a number of event log exceptions such as: A failure was reported when trying to invoke a service application: EndpointFailure OWSTIMER
Service Application Uri: urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:service:d87cf6e6a3374450b42d90af49164091#authority=urn:uuid:5717a627251143b99e95dd553149073c&authority=https://server 1:32844/Topology/topology.svc 
Active Endpoints: 1
Failed Endpoints:1
Affected Endpoint: http://server 1:32843/d87cf6e6a3374450b42d90af49164091/ProfileService.svc

Comment: why do i still not see the new server in the topology?

Answer (score 0):

The command that worked with all servers running was:

```
$hostA = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance -Identity "WFE 1"
$hostB = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance -Identity "WFE 2"
Start-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance -Identity $hostA
Start-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance -Identity $hostB

Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance -Identity $hostA
Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance -Identity $hostB

$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
$newTopology = New-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -SearchApplication $ssa


New-SPEnterpriseSearchAdminComponent -SearchTopology $newTopology -SearchServiceInstance $hostA
New-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlComponent -SearchTopology $newTopology -SearchServiceInstance $hostA
New-SPEnterpriseSearchContentProcessingComponent -SearchTopology $newTopology -SearchServiceInstance $hostA
New-SPEnterpriseSearchAnalyticsProcessingComponent -SearchTopology $newTopology -SearchServiceInstance $hostA
New-SPEnterpriseSearchQueryProcessingComponent -SearchTopology $newTopology -SearchServiceInstance $hostA
New-SPEnterpriseSearchIndexComponent -SearchTopology $newTopology -SearchServiceInstance $hostA -IndexPartition 0
New-SPEnterpriseSearchAdminComponent -SearchTopology $newTopology -SearchServiceInstance $hostB
New-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlComponent -SearchTopology $newTopology -SearchServiceInstance $hostB
New-SPEnterpriseSearchContentProcessingComponent -SearchTopology $newTopology -SearchServiceInstance $hostB
New-SPEnterpriseSearchAnalyticsProcessingComponent -SearchTopology $newTopology -SearchServiceInstance $hostB
New-SPEnterpriseSearchQueryProcessingComponent -SearchTopology $newTopology -SearchServiceInstance $hostB
New-SPEnterpriseSearchIndexComponent -SearchTopology $newTopology -SearchServiceInstance $hostB -IndexPartition 0
```

> Name                                            State     Description
>   ----                                            -----     -----------
>   IndexComponent2                                 Active
>   Cell:IndexComponent2-SP0715ab4d49c9I.1.0        Active
>   Partition:0                                     Active
>   AdminComponent1                                 Unknown
>   QueryProcessingComponent1                       Unknown
>   ContentProcessingComponent1                     Unknown
>   AnalyticsProcessingComponent1                   Unknown
>   IndexComponent1                                 Unknown
>   AdminComponent2                                 Active
>   QueryProcessingComponent2                       Active
>   ContentProcessingComponent2                     Active
>   AnalyticsProcessingComponent2                   Active
>   CrawlComponent1                                 Active
>   CrawlComponent0                                 Failed

Comment: After applying the above and turning off the first WFE server to test it again I receive a number of event log exceptions such as: A failure was reported when trying to invoke a service application: EndpointFailure OWSTIMER Service Application Uri: urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:service:d87cf6e6a3374450b42d90af49164091#authority=urn:uuid:5717a627251143b99e95dd553149073c&authority=server 1:32844/Topology/topology.svc Active Endpoints: 1 Failed Endpoints:1 Affected Endpoint: server 1:32843/d87cf6e6a3374450b42d90af49164091/ProfileService.svc

Comment: at the end you need to SET 'https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/set-spenterprisesearchtopology?view=sharepoint-ps' (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/change-the-default-search-topology)  or use https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/scottstewart/2015/04/29/powershell-ui-to-modify-sharepoint-search-topology/

Comment: I did. And then I turned one WFE off and ran  Get-SPEnterpriseSearchStatus -SearchApplication $ssa and I got what I pasted in my edit above

Comment: with the above command, search is not working properly now even after re-indexing and running a full crawl - any ideas ?!

Comment: can you add screenshot of your new topology stats from the Search Administration? Any errors?